# Is it possible to extract specific data from a table that is formed by XMLSchema?

Tags: javascript, xml, html-table, xmlschemaset, xml-schema-collection

I would like to extract data inside a webpage. The data is formed with http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema .

The data that will be extracted is located in different `<td>` tags in a table. The table is automatically formed when the text is pasted to the `<textarea>`.

How can I extract specific parts of the text from these `<td>` tags?

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Comment: Yes, I can use also jquery. There is no restriction about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success parsing XML docs using the code after pulling it from an ajax request:

```
var putData; // where the selected tags name will be put
  $(xmlDoc).find('tagName').each(function(){// search within each <tagname> element
   putData = $(this).find('embeddedTagName').text();// pull the data out from the <embeddedTagName> within <tagName>
  });
```

This will search for the tag named `<tagName>` and search within it for `<embeddedTagName>` to give the included text. This will be done for each `<tagName>` element.

If there are a multitude of tags you will be searching within, I would suggest using an array or object to organize your pulled data.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, if it answered your question feel free to mark it as the answer, thanks.